# google maps, google places and save marker to a database

Tags: php, mysql, maps

First of all I would like to tell you that I am not sure if I use the terms correctly so please excuse me for any misunderstandings. I will try to clear everything.

What I want to do is to let the users on my website to select their favorite bar or restaurant and add it to their profile.

It should be more or less like maps.google.com but in a smaller dimensions let's say 400x400. The users will be able to search for a place and once they find it they will be able to save it to their profile.

I am confused though because Google offers the Google Maps and the Google Places. I do not see any tutorials around regarding Google Places..

The question is.. Can I do my small project by using google maps or I really need to use google places?

Is there any tutorial/link which shows how to store on my database the current map location?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more searching I found my answer which was pretty simple.

It looks like I can get the lat and lng from place.geometry.location .

The rest about storing it to the database is easy!

Thanks anyone who at least read my post!

Cheers!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: Are you trying to find the lng and lat from google maps object?

Comment: I am searching for this part "It should be more or less like maps.google.com but in a smaller dimensions let's say 400x400. The users will be able to search for a place and once they find it, save it to the database."